# Creating list of beans based on property file in spring

Tags: spring, properties

I would like to create list of beans based on property files in spring. To illustrate the problem lets say I have a `ClassRoom`.

```
public class ClassRoom {

  private List<Student> students;

  public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
      this.students = students;
  }
}

public class Student {
  private Strign firstName;
  private String lastName;

  /* cosntructor, setters, getters ... */
}
```

So normally I will do in my .xml spring config:

...

```
<property name="student">
  <list>
    <bean id="student1" class="Student" ...>
       <property name="firstName" value="${student.name}" />
       <property name="lastName" value="${student.surname}" />
    </bean>
    ...
  </list>
<property>
```

But now I have several property files - one per each environment, the corrent one is included based on system property which defines the environment - and the number of students is different in each environment.

So what I'm looking for is having property file like:

```
student.1.fistName=Paul
student.1.lastName=Verlaine
student.2.firstName=Alex
student.2.lastName=Hamburger
```

And some nice utility which converts such file into `List` of my `Student` classes.

Sofar I went with having separate .xml configuration file for the list of students which is being included into my spring configuration but I don't particularly like the idea of providing part of the xml configuration to the client. I believe this should be separated.

So the question: is there any cool spring utility which can do this for me? Or is it up to me to write one?

Comment: I would use the constructor(or @PostConstruct method) of the ClassRoom to read all the property files and init the students.

Comment: This is definitely an option but I was wondering whether I can avoid such manual step as this sounds like pretty common problem to me.

Comment: I also edited the question so it is clear that there is always only single files in play but I want to be able to define various number of students based on the property file.

Comment: I think that you need to implement this, because it is very specific requirement, so I have highly doubt that spring support this out of the box. BTW I recommend to use a factory bean.

Comment: Hm, it's a shame because I'm lazy :) Yes, will do it myself probably. The question was aiming to the scenario when you have a list of beans which is of various size in each environment - which I believe is pretty common pattern ... ?

Comment: Finally it wasn't that bad. But I can understand why there is no really generic solution now ;-)

Comment: It's seem to be easier like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381060/spring-dynamically-creating-beans-from-application-properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I decided to prove I'm not that lazy. The solution has some obvious limitations like 1 level of properties or being able t oset primitives types only. But meets my needs. So for record:

Property file:

```
student.1.firstName=Jan
student.1.lastName=Zyka
student.1.age=30
student.2.firstName=David
student.2.lastName=Kalita
student.2.age=55
```

Student class:

```
package com.jan.zyka.test.dao;

public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String common;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getCommon() {
        return common;
    }

    public void setCommon(String common) {
        this.common = common;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", common='" + common + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Spring definition:

```
<bean id="studentFactory" class="com.jan.zyka.test.BeanListFactory">
    <property name="propertyPrefix" value="student" />
    <property name="commonProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="common" value="testCommonValue" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="targetType">
        <value type="java.lang.Class">com.jan.zyka.test.dao.Student</value>
    </property>
    <property name="properties">
        <util:properties location="classpath:testListFactory.properties" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Results in:

```
[
 Student{firstName='Jan', lastName='Zyka', age=30, common='testCommonValue'},  
 Student{firstName='David', lastName='Kalita', age=55, common='testCommonValue'}
]
```

Factory bean itself:

```
package com.jan.zyka.test;

import com.google.common.primitives.Primitives;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;

import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * <p>
 *    Creates list of beans based on property file.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 *    Each object should be defined in the property file as follows:
 *    <pre>
 *        &lt;prefix&gt;.&lt;index&gt;.&lt;property&gt;
 *    </pre>
 *
 *    So one example might be:
 *    <pre>
 *        student.1.firstName=Paul
 *        student.1.lastName=Verlaine
 *        student.2.firstName=Alex
 *        student.2.lastName=Hamburger
 *    </pre>
 *
 *    The target class must provide default constructor and setter for each property defined in the configuration file as per
 *    bean specification.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param <T> type of the target object
 */
public class BeanListFactory<T> implements FactoryBean<List<T>> {

    private String propertyPrefix;
    private Map<String, Object> commonProperties = Collections.emptyMap();
    private Class<T> targetType;
    private Properties properties;

    private List<T> loadedBeans;

    public String getPropertyPrefix() {
        return propertyPrefix;
    }

    public void setPropertyPrefix(String propertyPrefix) {
        this.propertyPrefix = propertyPrefix;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getCommonProperties() {
        return commonProperties;
    }

    public void setCommonProperties(Map<String, Object> commonProperties) {
        this.commonProperties = commonProperties;
    }

    public Class<T> getTargetType() {
        return targetType;
    }

    public void setTargetType(Class<T> targetType) {
        this.targetType = targetType;
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getObject() throws Exception {

        loadedBeans = new ArrayList<T>();
        int lastIndex = -1;

        T item = null;

        for (String property: prefixFilteredProperties()) {

            // The actual value
            final String propertyValue = properties.getProperty(property);

            // Remove Prefix
            property = property.substring(propertyPrefix.length() + 1);

            // Split by "."
            String tokens[] = property.split("\\.");

            if (tokens.length != 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Each list property must be in form of: <prefix>.<index>.<property name>");
            }

            final int index = Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]);
            final String propertyName = tokens[1];

            // New index
            if (lastIndex != index) {
                if (lastIndex !=-1) {
                    loadedBeans.add(item);
                }
                lastIndex = index;

                item = targetType.newInstance();
                setCommonProperties(item, commonProperties);
            }

            // Set the property
            setProperty(item, propertyName, convertIfNecessary(propertyName, propertyValue));
        }

        // Add last item
        if (lastIndex != -1) {
            loadedBeans.add(item);
        }

        return loadedBeans;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ArrayList.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    private Object convertIfNecessary(String propertyName, String propertyValue) throws Exception {
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(targetType, propertyName);
        Class<?> propertyType = Primitives.wrap(descriptor.getPropertyType());

        if (propertyType == String.class) {
            return propertyValue;
        }

        return propertyType.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(propertyType, propertyValue);
    }

    private Set<String> prefixFilteredProperties() {
        Set<String> filteredProperties = new TreeSet<String>();

        for (String propertyName: properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            if (propertyName.startsWith(this.propertyPrefix)) {
                filteredProperties.add(propertyName);
            }
        }

        return filteredProperties;
    }

    private void setCommonProperties(T item, Map<String, Object> commonProperties) throws Exception {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> commonProperty: commonProperties.entrySet()) {
            setProperty(item, commonProperty.getKey(), commonProperty.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static void setProperty(Object item, String propertyName, Object value) throws Exception {
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(item.getClass(), propertyName);
        descriptor.getWriteMethod().invoke(item, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the same is possible with @ConfigurationProperties from Spring boot

Answer (score 5):

Posting this Spring Boot specific solution in hope to help others still trying to find the answer. Mapping property file to a list of beans is possible out of the box with spring. You need to have a ConfigurationProperties bean with a collection of your beans inside and use a proper naming convention as shown below.

Look into my working example:

I have a wrapper bean with ConfigurationProperties:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "notification")
@Data
@Valid
public class NotificationProperties {
    @NotNull
    private Set<AlertThreshold> alertThresholds;
    @NotNull
    private Set<Subscriber> subscribers;
}
```

The following properties in application.properties (there is an alternative way with yaml) will map into NotificationProperties file creating sets of beans:

```
notification.alert-thresholds[0].step=PB
notification.alert-thresholds[0].status=RDY
notification.alert-thresholds[0].threshold=500

notification.alert-thresholds[1].step=LA
notification.alert-thresholds[1].status=RDY
notification.alert-thresholds[1].threshold=100

notification.subscribers[0].email=subscriber1@gmail.com
notification.subscribers[1].email=subscriber2@gmail.com
```

Here're other model classes participating in this configuration:

```
@Data
public class AlertThreshold {
    @NotNull
    private String step;
    @NotNull
    private String status;
    @NotNull
    private Integer threshold;
}

@Data
public class Subscriber {
    @Email
    private String email;
}
```