# Spring: PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer incrementing integer infix property name

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm trying to use PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer to read properties of this type:

```
server.0.name=aaa
server.0.port=9999
server.1.name=bbb
server.1.port=9998
...
server.n.name=serverName
server.n.port=serverPort
```

Is there any way to inject it as a list of servers? `List<Server> servers;` 
Where the Server is some bean.

Comment: I've found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382065/creating-list-of-beans-based-on-property-file-in-spring?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can not do this is that you are trying to create new `Server` Instances. The `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` is afaik not able to create beans. But you can set the property in the beans definition

```
<bean id="server" class="ParentClass">
    <property name="servers">
        <list>
            <bean class="Server">
                <property name="name" value="aaa"/>
                <property name="port" value="123"/>
            </bean>
            ...
            more beans
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```