# Spring - Dynamically Creating Beans from application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I have a need to create multiple beans of the same name using properties file. For example:

```
rabbit.example.language[0]=java
rabbit.example.framework[0]=spring
rabbit.example.language[1]=python
rabbit.example.framework[1]=django
```

I'd like to create a Bean for each example index (this will ultimately be used for Rabbit Queues, but I'm simplifying things). Here's some code I'm working with so far.

Rabbits.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="example")
public class Rabbits {
    private String language;
    private String framework;

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language= language;
    }

    public String getFramework() {
        return framework;
    }

    public void setFramework(String framework) {
        this.framework= framework;
    }
}
```

Properties.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rabbit")
public class Properties {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private List<Rabbits> rabbits = new ArrayList<Rabbits>();

    public List<Rabbits> getRabbits() {
        return rabbits;
    }

    public void setRabbits(List<Rabbits> rabbits) {
        this.rabbits = rabbits;
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitFlowProcessor rabbitFlowProcessor(List<Rabbits> rabbit){
        return new RabbitFlowProcessor(rabbit);
    }

}
```

RabbitFlowProcessor.java:

```
@Component
public class RabbitFlowProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private List<Rabbits> rabbits;

    public RabbitFlowProcessor(List<Rabbits> rabbits) {
        this.rabbits = rabbits;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory  beanFactory) throws BeansException {
      rabbits.stream()
              .forEach(rabbit -> {
                  System.out.println(rabbit.getLanguage());
              });
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the output to be Java Python, but the "rabbits" are coming back as null. Can anyone tell where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Please update your codes with following comments:

```
rabbit.example[0].language=java
rabbit.example[0].framework=spring
rabbit.example[1].language=python
rabbit.example[1].framework=django
```

As the example will be a List, so you need add the index with it.

---

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rabbit")
public class RabbitsProperties {

    private List<Rabbits> example = new ArrayList<Rabbits>();

    public List<Rabbits> getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public void setExample(List<Rabbits> example) {
        this.example = example;
    }
}
```

About the `NestedConfigurationProperty` annoation, that indicates that a field in a `ConfigurationProperties` object should be treated as if it were a nested type. 
This annotation has no bearing on the actual binding processes, but it is used by the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` as a hint that a field is not bound as a single value.

---

```
public class Rabbits {
    private String language;
    private String framework;

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language= language;
    }

    public String getFramework() {
        return framework;
    }

    public void setFramework(String framework) {
        this.framework= framework;
    }
}
```

typically, you can add this as a nested inner class in `RabbitsProperties`

Then in your `RabbitFlowProcessor.java`, you can inject the `RabbitsProperties` as normal.

```
@Component
public class RabbitFlowProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitsProperties rabbitsProperties; 
    ......
}
```